# Rcpp function to conditionally replace particular elements in a data frame with list columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rcpp

I am trying to acquaint myself with the Rcpp package. I have a data frame **df** and I wish to replace all values less than 6 with 6 and all values above 8 with 8 ...I want to leave all other values in tact:

```
>df<-data.frame(w= 1:3, x=3:5, y=6:8, z = I(list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)))

>df<-as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, 
                                 lapply(df[1:3],
                                 function(x) Map("*", df$z, x)))) 

>df 
            w             x             y
1        1, 2          3, 6         6, 12
2     2, 4, 6      4, 8, 12     7, 14, 21
3 3, 6, 9, 12 5, 10, 15, 20 8, 16, 24, 32
```

I have attempted this code which works only partly.

```
library(Rcpp)

DataFrame replace(DataFrame df) {
    R_xlen_t nCols = df.cols();
    R_xlen_t nRows = df.rows();
    List result(nCols * nRows);
    result.attr("dim") = Dimension(nRows, nCols);
    colnames(result) = as<CharacterVector>(df.names());

    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < nCols; ++i) {
        List column = as<List>(df[i]);
        for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < nRows; ++j) {
            NumericVector tmp = as<NumericVector>(column[j]);
            if(tmp[j] < 6){
             tmp[j] = 6;
             } else if(tmp[j] > 8){
             tmp[j] = 8;
             }else {
             tmp[j] = tmp[j];
             result[i * nCols + j] =  tmp;
             }
        }
        DataFrame df1(result); 
        return df1;
    }')

>replace(df)

            w            x            y
1        6, 2         6, 6        6, 12
2     2, 6, 6     4, 6, 12     7, 6, 21
3 3, 6, 6, 12 5, 10, 6, 20 8, 16, 6, 32
```

I wish to have a hint on the error in my code. My expected output is:

```
>out

#           w          x          y
#1       6, 6       6, 6       6, 8
#2    6, 6, 6    6, 8, 8    7, 8, 8
#3 6, 6, 8, 8 6, 8, 8, 8 8, 8, 8, 8
```

Comment: Just a kind word of advice. I've been reading your post over the past few days and noticed that your code formatting makes it incredibly difficult to read.  Most experienced programmers have some sort of consistent spacing scheme to break up and organize the flow of their code, which makes it easier on the eye. There are several examples on SO (including the answer below by @QiangKou) and there are also several google hits for "spacing convention programming" or "style guide c++", etc.

Comment: @JosephWood Thanks a lot for the kind advice. Corrected but the down vote remains. Can the down vote be changed?

Comment: The down vote was not me. SO can be tough, especially for new users and oftentimes a post will get down voted simply because of bad formatting. I will say that the tag you have been posting in (i.e. Rcpp) has some very helpful and knowledgable people to help guide you. Just keep in mind that the help is free and quite a bit of research is a strong prerequisite. Thanks for your accepting attitude and I hope my words have helped you.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you forgot to loop over `tmp`

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
            DataFrame replace(DataFrame df) {

              R_xlen_t nCols = df.cols();
              R_xlen_t nRows = df.rows();
              List result(nCols * nRows);
              result.attr("dim") = Dimension(nRows, nCols);
              colnames(result) = as<CharacterVector>(df.names());

              for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < nCols; ++i) {
                List column = as<List>(df[i]);
                for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < nRows; ++j) {
                  NumericVector tmp = as<NumericVector>(column[j]);
                  for (R_xlen_t k = 0; k < tmp.size(); k++) {
                    if(tmp[k] < 6){
                      tmp[k] = 6;
                    } else if(tmp[k] > 8){
                      tmp[k] = 8;
                    } else {
                      tmp[k] = tmp[k];
                    }
                  }

                  result[i * nCols + j] =  tmp;
                }
              }
              DataFrame df1(result); 
              return df1;
            }')

df<- data.frame(w= 1:3, x=3:5, y=6:8, z = I(list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)))

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df[1:3], function(x) Map("*", df$z, x))))

replace(df)
```

Then we got

```
> df
            w             x             y
1        1, 2          3, 6         6, 12
2     2, 4, 6      4, 8, 12     7, 14, 21
3 3, 6, 9, 12 5, 10, 15, 20 8, 16, 24, 32
> replace(df)
           w          x          y
1       6, 6       6, 6       6, 8
2    6, 6, 6    6, 8, 8    7, 8, 8
3 6, 6, 8, 8 6, 8, 8, 8 8, 8, 8, 8
```